# Kafka JSON Object Error: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, quarkus, json-deserialization

I have an error deserializing this JSON string from kafka into java object.

```
{"type":"CASA","batchList":["CVA348856650375401ABC","BNM346846350035548DEF"]}
```

My deserialization code is this:

```
 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
 FooDTO fooDto = objectMapper.readValue(payload.value(), new TypeReference<FooDTO>() {});
```

I also did try the following

```
//objectMapper.readValue(payload.value(), FooDTO.class);
//objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object), FooDTO.class));
//objectMapper.readValue(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object), new TypeReference<FooDTO>()));
```

and nothing is working. Then I thought it has something to do with the whitespaces and nextlines because when I manually add the json string in the code ie: `String jsonString = "{\"type\":\"CASA\",\"batchList\":[\"CVA348856650375401ABC\",\"BNM346846350035548DEF\"]}";` the deserialization code works.

the next lines or *"\n"* is not removing. I tried the following:

```
String jsonStringReplace = payload.value().replace("\n", "");
String jsonStringTrim = payload.value().trim();
String jsonStringStrip = payload.value().strip();
String jsonStringRegex = payload.value().replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");
```

all is like this:

```
raw: "{\n \"type\": \"CASA\",\n  \"batchList\": [\n    \"CVA348856650375401ABC\",\n    \"BNM346846350035548DEF\"\n  ]\n}"
jsonStringRepAll: "{\n \"type\": \"CASA\",\n  \"batchList\": [\n    \"CVA348856650375401ABC\",\n    \"BNM346846350035548DEF\"\n  ]\n}"
jsonStringTrim: "{\n  \"type\": \"CASA\",\n  \"batchList\": [\n    \"CVA348856650375401ABC\",\n    \"BNM346846350035548DEF\"\n  ]\n}"
jsonStringStrip: "{\n  \"type\": \"CASA\",\n  \"batchList\": [\n    \"CVA348856650375401ABC\",\n    \"BNM346846350035548DEF\"\n  ]\n}"
jsonStringRegex: "{\n \"type\": \"CASA\",\n  \"batchList\": [\n    \"CVA348856650375401ABC\",\n    \"BNM346846350035548DEF\"\n  ]\n}"
```

I always got the same error over and over again:

```
Cannot construct instance of `sample.ms.dto.FooDTO` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{
  "type": "CASA",
  "batchList": [
    "CVA348856650375401ABC",
    "BNM346846350035548DEF"
  ]
}')
```

The following is the code:

```
    @Incoming(KafkaConstants.KAFKA_TOPIC_REQUEST)
    @Acknowledgment(Acknowledgment.Strategy.POST_PROCESSING)
    @Blocking
    @Retry
    public Response consumeRequest(Record<String, String> payload) {
        log.info("+++++ START CONSUMING REQUEST +++++");
        log.debug("{} : {}", payload.key(), payload.value());
        try {
            if (Optional.ofNullable(payload.value()).isPresent()) {
 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
     FooDTO fooDto = objectMapper.readValue(payload.value(), new TypeReference<FooDTO>() 
{});
...
}
}
```

The code below is the DTO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Valid
public class FooDTO {

    //@NotNull
    private String batchKey;

    //@NotNull
    private String type;

    //@NotNull
    private List<String> batchList;
}
```

Comment: better add a full stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

First, in your code don't instantiate a new `ObjectMapper`for every request. Make it a member of the class that has your method `consumeRequest` and re-use it. Also, to make your code even simpler you can use a 3d party utility `JsonUtils` that is a thin wrapper over `ObjectMapper` class and can do what you are trying to do in one line:

```
FooDTO fooDto = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(jsonStr, FooDTO.class);
```

Your String `"{\"type\":\"CASA\",\"batchList\":[\"CVA348856650375401ABC\",\"BNM346846350035548DEF\"]}"` should be working fine. JsonUtils class comes with MgntUtils Open Source library written and maintained by me. Here is `JsonUtils Javadoc` and the library could be obtained as [Maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or on [GitHub](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and Javadoc)

Comment: The sample 

`String jsonString = "{\"type\":\"CASA\",\"batchList\":[\"CVA348856650375401ABC\",\"BNM346846350035548DEF\"]}"`

it's just an sample. all json or values should come from kafka. I did just try it for debug purposes.